# how to remove cartesian combination of records in join dbms

Tags: mysql

I have to tables income and expense in mysql.

Income table

```
sn
i_type
u_id
year
month
inc_amount
```

Expense table

```
sn
e_type
u_id
year
month
exp_amount
```

I want to join the two tables above to calculate sum of income, sum of expense monthly as well as yearly basis. I have written the following query:

```
select income.year,income.month,sum(income.inc_amount),sum(expense.exp_amount) 
from income,expense 
where income.u_id=expense.u_id, income.year=expense.year,income.month=expense.month 
group by income.year,income.month
```

The avoid query displays the Cartesian sum of the amount. i.e if there are three records of a particular u_id,year, month in income table and 2 records of the same u_id, year, month. It gives the sum of income amount 2 times the actual amount since 1 record of first income table combines with two records of expense table. In the same way the sum of expense amount is 3 times since each record of second table combines with 3 record in first table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION with both tables and then get aggregates.

```
select ie.year, ie.month, sum(ie.inc_amount), sum(ie.exp_amount)
from 
     (
     select year, month, inc_amount, 0 as exp_amount from income
     UNION
     select year, month, 0 as inc_amount, exp_amount from expense
     ) ie
group by ie.year, ie.month
```

Notice I've added an extra field on every table with 0 value, just to get same number of fields in final result.